# Uploading file IFormFile to Azure C# function

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, iformfile

I have this regular C# Azure function:

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log) ...
```

And I need to upload here file, e.g. image. How can I add here `IFormFile` or is there other way to upload file to function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To upload a file to an Azure Function, have a look at the Form of the incoming `HttpRequest`.

This works for me:

```cs
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "files")] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)
{
    foreach(var file in req.Form.Files)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var file = req.Form.Files[0];
            await file.CopyToAsync(ms);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            // Do something with the file
        }
    }

    return new OkResult();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but not I have another problem. This exceptions is thrown with any file: `System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Function1. Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities: Multipart body length limit 16384 exceeded.`

Comment: This is a new question that deserves its own question . But: [SO:40364226]

Comment: Thank you, solved by adding this attribute `[RequestFormLimits(ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue, MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue)]`

Comment: If my post answered your questions please mark it as the answer to help future users stumbling upon this question.

Comment: Could you also recommend how can I add form file and string params to same azure function method?